# Why does DynamoDB seem to inconsistently return LastEvaluatedKey when no records remain, depending on the record limit of the query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Using javascript aws-sdk and querying a dynamodb table, with document client. the table contains **10 elements** and the query **limit = 5**.

For each request I use the LastEvaluatedKey to build a new query and send a fresh request, here are the results :

```
first request --> {Items: Array(5), Count: 5, ScannedCount: 5, LastEvaluatedKey: {…}}
second request --> {Items: Array(5), Count: 5, ScannedCount: 5, LastEvaluatedKey: {…}}
third request --> {Items: Array(0), Count: 0, ScannedCount: 0}
```

According to this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination)

> If the result contains a LastEvaluatedKey element, proceed to step 2. 
>   **If there is not a LastEvaluatedKey in the result, then there are no
>   more items to be retrieved**

It is supposed to not return *LastEvaluatedKey* in the second request, cause there is no more elements, but it returns one which send to an empty result in the third request.

When i try with **limit = 4**, every things works as expected

```
first request --> {Items: Array(4), Count: 4, ScannedCount: 4, LastEvaluatedKey: {…}}
second request --> {Items: Array(4), Count: 4, ScannedCount: 4, LastEvaluatedKey: {…}}
third request --> {Items: Array(2), Count: 2, ScannedCount: 2} <--- there is no LastEvaluatedKey as expected
```

So what is happening here ?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I suggest raising this on the AWS forums.

Comment: ok, thank you, i will.

Comment: I assume when aws hits the limit '5' it just records the key and since it doesn't look further ahead it doesn't know how much items left to scan. Fairly a simple logic

Comment: @CanSahin this is what i want to know, if it is " according to the doc " an expected result, or not. I would have liked a sourced comment.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected.

This statement is true:

> If there is not a LastEvaluatedKey in the result, then there are no more items to be retrieved

However, you appear to be assuming that it implies the inverse condition is also true, but it isn't...

> If there are no more items to be retrieved, then there is not a LastEvaluatedKey in the result #false

This isn't implied by the first statement, it isn't logically equivalent, and isn't true.

If the service hits your limit exactly, then it does not know whether there may be more matching records to find, so it gives you the last record evaluated so that you can continue the search on the next request.  There may be more, there may not be.  This is an inevitable consequence of the optimization necessary to get the results back to you as quickly as possible.  Otherwise, the service would need to continue looking for at least one more match, even though it has already found enough to satisfy your limit.

If the search reaches the end without also reaching your limit, it knows there's nothing more to search for, so it does not return a `LastEvaluatedKey`.

Comment: Very good and I am glad to know this.  However it is rather sad that dynamodb can't just cleanly tell you whether there are more items.  For instance it could have returned the NextKeyValue instead.  If there are no more it is guaranteed empty/not present.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins it can't do that, because it doesn't yet know.  When the requested limit is reached, the fastest thing for the service to do is to stop looking and return the response immediately.  The next request is what tells it to continue looking and where to start looking to see if there are more.  Any other implementation would require a delay in the response while it checks whether any more items match.  This is the most efficient design in terms of both responsiveness and resource usage.

Answer (score 9):

Actualy i found that it's an expected result according to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#API_Query_ResponseSyntax)

> **LastEvaluatedKey**
>
> ...
>
> ***If LastEvaluatedKey is not empty, it does not necessarily mean that
>   there is more data in the result set. The only way to know when you
>   have reached the end of the result set is when LastEvaluatedKey is
>   empty.***
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is looking for this and like me needs a solution to work around the limitations of DynamoDB, here is how I implemented the backend  to tell the client if there are more items after the current request with a given limit.

Basically what one can do is to fetch one more item as the limit requested by the client. If DynamoDB returns limit + 1 items, we can tell the client there is more.
We also have to pop out the extra item and adjust the LastEvaluatedKey on our own in this case.

Example code for Node:

```
const clientLimit = 5;

const dynamodb = new DynamoDBClient({ region: REGION });
const command = new QueryCommand({
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':pkVal': { S: 'Organization' },
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :pkVal',
    Limit: clientLimit + 1,
    ExclusiveStartKey: parsePaginationToken(paginationToken),
});

const res = await dynamodb.send(command);

let lastEvaluatedKey;
if (res.Items.length === clientLimit + 1) {
    res.Items.pop();

    lastEvaluatedKey = {
        PK: res.Items[res.Items.length - 1].PK,
        SK: res.Items[res.Items.length - 1].SK,
    };
}

return {
    items: res.Items.map(orgFromItem),
    paginationToken: stringifyPaginationToken(lastEvaluatedKey),
};
```

Comment: Nice! I used the same work around to accomplish this. The one issue I see with your solution is you assume that the lastEvaluatedKey consists of a PK and an SK, which may work for certain tables but perhaps not others (for example, in cases where you're using a global secondary index.) I had to implement this solution in a generic db client function to list items in Go and accomplished it by dynamically determining the keys in the LastEvaluatedKey and then copying the values matching the dynamodbav tag from fields in my model definition using reflection. This would definitely be simpler in js.